# Reference on the Veblen-Young characterization of projective spaces

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, incidence-geometry

Can someone point me to a modern treatment of the Veblen-Young characterization of projective spaces of dimension greater than $2$ as $P(V)$ for some vector space $V$?

[**Added**: see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Axioms_for_projective_space) for a statement of the Veblen-Young Theorem.  The article includes a reference to the two-volume work of Veblen and Young in which the result was first proved. --PLC]

A precise reference to the original work where this appeared would also be very useful!

Comment: @Mariano: well, I guess I'm not your guy for this, but...I really don't understand the question at all.  I would have thought that every projective space is the projectivization of a vector space *by definition*.  Are you talking about some kind of abstract projective geometry, or...what?

Comment: @Pete: based on the comment "dimension greater than $2$" I am guessing that yes, this refers to an abstract notion of projective space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Axioms_for_projective_space .

Comment: @Qiaochu: thanks.  I took the liberty of editing that link into the question.  I hope Mariano will not mind.

Comment: Isn't this in Artin's "Geometric Algebra"? (for some value of "modern")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2-volume book by Veblen and Young is an obvious reference for the original proof. A modern reformulation of their result is the work of Tits classifying buildings of rank at least 3 in terms of algebraic groups over fields.

Comment: Ah. I thought the result might have been published before the book in 'paper' form. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, I think that's a good way to view this work of Tits: as a massive generalization of this theorem to other types of incidence geometries. 

Answer (score 2):

Here are some modern treatments:

1. [Projective Geometries: From Foundations to Applications](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/beutel.pdf),
   Albrecht Beutelspacher (1998) - see chapter 3 for the Veblen-Young
   characterisation.
2. [Points and Lines](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642156267), Ernest E. Shult (2011) - covers the
   characterisation results of other types of incidence geometries as
   well.